# React native modal error evaluating _this5.state.error[key]

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, settimeout

i'm still new to react native and i'm trying to make a modal with timer and i got an error say undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this5.state.error[key]') i tried to open the modal with setTimeout(), i think it has the problem with the state, anyone has an idea to fix it? Thanks

here is my code

```js
class FormInput extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const { fields, error } = props;

        this.state = this.createState(fields, error);

        this.state = {
            visible: false
        }

        //bind functions
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.timer = setTimeout(this.showModal, 5000); //auto reset after 60 seconds of inactivity
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }

    showModal() {
        this.setState ({ visible: true})
    }

    closeModal() {
        this.setState ({ visible: false})
    }
    
        createState(fields, error) {
        const state = {};
        fields.forEach((field) => {
            let { key, type, value, mandatory } = field;
            state[key] = { type: type, value: value, mandatory: mandatory };
        })

        state["error"] = error;
        state["submitted"] = false;

        return state;
    }

    
    
    render() {

        return (
                <View>
                    <AlertModal visible={this.showModal} close={this.closeModal}/>
                    </View>

        );
```

Comment: Can you link the library from where you are using `AlertModal`?

Comment: i'm using react-native-modal https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `showModal` and `closeModal` an arrow function

```
showModal = () => {
  this.setState ({ visible: true })
}

closeModal = () => {
  this.setState ({ visible: false })
}
```

or bind them in constructor.

Also `visible` prop is a boolean and you are passing a function. Pass `this.state.visible` to fix the issue.

```
<AlertModal visible={this.state.visible} close={this.closeModal} />
```

--- UPDATED ---

So after checking out your updated code, I was able to figure out what was the issue. In constructor you are doing this

```
        this.state = this.createState(fields, error);

        this.state = {
            visible: false
        }
```

which overrides `this.state`. So I will suggest you to move `visible: false` into createState function and remove it from constructor.

Answer (score 0):

declare showModal as a arrow function

```
showModal = () => {
  this.setState ({ visible: true})
}
```

or bind the context for showModal

```
this.timer = setTimeout(this.showModal.bind(this), 5000)
```

or

```
this.timer = setTimeout(() => {this.showModal()}, 5000)
```

[learn more about javascript context this](https://codeburst.io/javascript-context-this-keyword-9a78a19d5786)